# Purescript Eff Monad: using non-native computational effects

Tags: functional-programming, monads, effect, purescript, purely-functional

I want to be able to write

```
x :: Eff (reader :: Reader Int, maybe :: Maybe) Int
x = do
  config <- ask -- configuration from (Reader Int) monad
  just config -- using (Maybe) Monad

runX :: Int
runX = runPure (runMaybe doIfNothing (runReader 6 x)) -- outputs: 6
```

using the `Eff` Monad

Is this possible to do using `Eff`?

If not how can we make it work not using `Eff`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MaybeT` and `ReaderT` monad transformers on top of `Eff`, but you cannot match the two in the way you wrote above:

```
import Prelude
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Class
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console
import Control.Monad.Maybe.Trans
import Control.Monad.Reader.Trans

x :: ReaderT Int (MaybeT (Eff (console :: CONSOLE))) Int
x = do
  liftEff (log "Asking...")
  config <- ask
  pure config

main :: Eff (console :: CONSOLE) (Maybe Int)
main = runMaybeT (runReaderT x 6)
```

Comment: I don't like monad transformers, Iv'e seen some talks where something like Purescript's Eff monad was used with monads like Reader, but I don't know if it's possible to do in Purescript, maybe we need to define a new monad similar to Eff.